# OnBackPress App is crash when back From Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am using drawer menu in my app.I select one option from menu and open fragment and from that fragment call an Activity.Since here it is working fine but when I press back button(OnbackPress) then app is crashed.
bellow is the error.
"Unable start activity...ClassCastException...cannot be cast to Home_Tab"

This is MainActivity code.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        homefragment = Home_tab()
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction!!.replace(R.id.frame, homefragment)
        fragmentTransaction!!.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction!!.commit()
    } else {
        homefragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments[0] as Home_tab //Crash at this line 
 }
```

Code from where backPress Called.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    finish()
}
```

Comment: Could you please update with your Home_tab class code as well. Looks like it is not the same to what you are trying to cast.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the stack trace to know what the error is? Might wanna add it to the question so we know what went wrong too :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Add a check like this before casting. 
//It is a smart cast and you can directly use the result.
Fragment fragmentZero = supportFragmentManager.fragments[0]
if (fragmentZero is Home_tab) {
   //Casting is done, you can directly use fragment here
   homefragment = fragmentZero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well based on your code you add the fragment to the fragmentmanager (regular one) but try to get it back from the supportfragmentmanager. Those are two different classes and your fragment can only extend one

Answer (score 0):

You're are mixin fragment manager et support fragment manager, i'll go with suppport one since this is the right way to do it. To get current display fragment added with a container ID use `findFragmentById`

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        homefragment = Home_tab()
        supportFragmentManager?.let{
            fragmentTransaction = it.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, homefragment)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }
    } else {
        homefragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame) as Home_tab
 }
```

Comment: I have replaced my code with this.It is working fine in other devices but in Redmi 4 device the app is crashing.Device configuration are: Android OS 7.1.2 N2G47H,MIUI version MIUI Global 9.2|Stable 9.2.4.0(NAMMIEK),2GB RAM,16GB ROM.CPU octa-core Max 1.10GHz.

Comment: octa-core Max 1.40GHz